# How to force the input of a textbox on a userform to be a specific format in VBA

Tags: vba, input, textbox, controls

I have a user form with a series of input textboxes and am looking for a way to prevent the user from inputing anything other than 5 digits followed by one letter followed by 4 digits. E.g. *12345A6789*

I can see a way to use only numeric and only alphabetic and create three text boxes and then somehow merge them all together- although not sure how to do that either. Ideally there would just be one textbox.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Could write an onchange handler to actively check that the input fits the format you expect.

Comment: You could use regex if you never need the code to work on a mac. Are you okay with no mac compatibility for the code?

Comment: Better title. Small text changes.

Comment: The document will be sent out to lots of people so there is a chance that some of them will be mac users.

Answer (score 1):

The built in `Textbox` is a little lacking in this department. The way I'd approach this would be to use the `Change` event to enforce formatting. Note that the Key* events won't handle any of the other ways to get text into a Textbox (drag-drop, copy-paste, etc.). Something along these lines (this is for zip + 4, but a similar concept would work):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Static reentry As Boolean                           'anti-recursion flag
    If reentry Then Exit Sub
    Dim chars() As Byte
    chars = StrConv(TextBox1.Text, vbFromUnicode)

    Dim buffer As String
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(chars) To UBound(chars)
        If Len(buffer) = 5 Then buffer = buffer & "-"   'auto-insert the dash
        If Len(buffer) = 10 Then Exit For               'limit to 10 chars
        If chars(i) >= 48 And chars(i) <= 57 Then       'ignore anything but numbers.
            buffer = buffer & Chr$(chars(i))
        End If
    Next i

    reentry = True
    TextBox1.Text = buffer
    reentry = False
End Sub
```

Comment: This was really helpful, thanks and I have got most of what I needed however I need the entry after the character to be a letter not a digit and so using ignoring anything but numbers doesn't work for my case.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that works okay, I'm sure this could be improved to prevent the user inputting special characters but this works well enough to reduce most errors

```
'Checks that document number is the correct format (5 digits, 1 letter, 4 digits)
Sub TextBox_DocumentNumber_AfterUpdate()

If (IsNumeric(Left(TextBox_DocumentNumber, 5))) = False Then
Call DocumentNumberFormat


ElseIf (IsNumeric(Mid(TextBox_DocumentNumber, 7))) = True Then
Call DocumentNumberFormat


ElseIf (IsNumeric(Right(TextBox_DocumentNumber, 4))) = False Then
Call DocumentNumberFormat

End If

End Sub



Sub DocumentNumberFormat()

Dim DocNum As String
Dim Response As VbMsgBoxResult

DocNum = MsgBox("Please enter document numbers in the formart 00000-A-0000", vbRetryCancel + vbExclamation, "Incorrect Format")


UserForm3.TextBox_DocumentNumber = ""
If DocNum = vbCancel Then
           Call Cancel
End If

Exit Sub
End Sub





'Auto inserts hyphens and sets max length for document number
Private Sub TextBox_DocumentNumber_Change()
If Len(TextBox_DocumentNumber) = 5 Then TextBox_DocumentNumber = TextBox_DocumentNumber & "-"
If Len(TextBox_DocumentNumber) = 7 Then TextBox_DocumentNumber = TextBox_DocumentNumber & "-"
TextBox_DocumentNumber.MaxLength = 12
End Sub
```